# Set SQL Server credentials in PowerShell script or invoke with credentials

Tags: sql-server, powershell, amazon-web-services, credentials

Below is my working PowerShell script for connecting to AWS SQL Server database. How can I set the credentials hard coded with in the script without the prompt or invoke the script with the credentials?

I have tried couple of options from the internet using `PSCredential`, `credentials`, `Get-WmiObject`, `SqlConnection` but none of them are working.

```
      $srv = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" "myBox"          

      #set the credentials here
      #This sets the connection to mixed-mode authentication
      $srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false; 

      #Prompt for user credentials 
      $credential = Get-Credential  

      #Deal with the extra backslash character 
      $loginName = $credential.UserName -replace("\\","")  

      #This sets the login name  
      $srv.ConnectionContext.set_Login($loginName);  

      #This sets the password  
      $srv.ConnectionContext.set_SecurePassword($credential.Password)

      #test the connection
      $srv.Databases | Select name
```

Comment: So you need to auth via some permanent login/pass? You can create user/login on SQL Server side and auth via it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $SQLInstance = "Instance Name"
    $Database = "Database"
    $ID = "User ID" 
    $Password = "Password"

function Invoke-Sqlcommand 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ServerInstance, 
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Database, 
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Query, 
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Username, 
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Password, 
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$QueryTimeout=600, 
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$ConnectionTimeout=15, 
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateScript({test-path $_})] [string]$InputFile, 
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateSet("DataSet", "DataTable", "DataRow")] [string]$As="DataRow" 
    ) 

    if ($InputFile) 
    { 
        $filePath = $(resolve-path $InputFile).path 
        $Query =  [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filePath") 
    } 

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 

    if ($Username) 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout } 
    else 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout } 

    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 

    #Following EventHandler is used for PRINT and RAISERROR T-SQL statements. Executed when -Verbose parameter specified by caller 
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose) 
    { 
        $conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors=$true 
        $handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {Write-Verbose "$($_)"} 
        $conn.add_InfoMessage($handler) 
    } 

    $conn.Open() 
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn) 
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout 
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd) 
    [void]$da.fill($ds) 
    $conn.Close() 
    switch ($As) 
    { 
        'DataSet'   { Write-Output ($ds) } 
        'DataTable' { Write-Output ($ds.Tables) } 
        'DataRow'   { Write-Output ($ds.Tables[0]) } 
    } 

} 


Invoke-Sqlcommand -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -Query "Query Goes here" -Username $ID -Password $Password
```

Using the above function, you can pass the user name and password  in plain texts for an SQL invoke from Powershell